# JMeter change CSV file when current file reach its last data

Tags: csv, jmeter

I have a script for stress test using JMeter, the problem is the data I will be using is too many that I needed to divide it to multiple CSVs.

Is it possible in JMeter to change the CSV file, the source of data if the file is at the last data ?

Example:
I have 1 million data in CSV, during run-time when the iteration gets to the 1 million data it will change the file with newer data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have multiple [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) with different variable names as id id1 id2

Mark as `Recycle on EOF` false

> Recycle on EOF? Should the file be re-read from the beginning on reaching EOF? (default is true)

And when you will get to the end check value is EOF as `"${id}" == "<EOF>"` and override id/use `${id1}` instead

Example:

```
if ("<EOF>".equals(vars.get("Email")){ 
   if ("<EOF>".equals(vars.get("Email2")){ 
      vars.put("Email",vars.get("Email3"));
      vars.put("Password",vars.get("Password3));
   } else {
      vars.put("Email",vars.get("Email2"));
      vars.put("Password",vars.get("Password2));
   }
}
```

Comment: is this applicable to if the variable name is the same  for every request? its not clear to me on how can i override the ${id} to ${id1}

Comment: @user9923622 you can add JSR223 Sampler with code `vars.put("id",vars.get("id1"))`

Comment: hello again sir, i am trying your suggestion with 3 files, but what is happening is the data of the second file is not used, the script only uses the data from file 1 and file 3,, can you help me again , thanks :)

Comment: i was trying this code :

if ("${Email}" == "<EOF>"){
 
 vars.put("Email","${Email2}");
 vars.put("Password","${Password2}");


 if("${Email2}" == "<EOF>"){
 
  vars.put("Email","${Email3}");
  vars.put("Password","${Password3}");
 }

}
@user7294900

Comment: @user9923622 see my update in answer, if it's not working please open a new question with more details

Comment: i realized now why it always enter  the IF clause, its because all the files are on the same row  so if CSV 1 is in EOF  its the same for CSV2, that is why it always uses CSV3 becasuse I did not  make recycle n EOF to false for CSV3. 
Now the question is how to revert back CSV2 to row 1.  
should i open a new  question for this ? @user7294900